# Unexpected value 'ImageUploadModule' imported by the module 'AppModule' in angular 2

Tags: angular

In my project, I used ng2-imageupload and installed through npm install ng2-imageupload.
when I run it in development mode, it run perfectly but if I run in production mode, it gives an error

i am using web pack versions is:

### "web pack": "2.1.0-beta.21", "web-pack-merge": "^0.14.1"

Comment: Which error does it give you?

Comment: Unexpected value 'ImageUploadModule' imported by the module 'AppModule'

Comment: Error: Unexpected value 'ImageUploadModule' imported by the module 'AppModule'
    at E:\Vishwanath\vasthu_Projet\Vasthu_1\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:14109:37